# Perl or Perl debugger optimizing "empty" `if``s?

Tags: perl, debugging, optimization

While developing some code, I ran some incomplete code where the `ìf`/`else` parts still need to be done. However the conditions call routines with a "side-effect", so I was expecting to be able to trace the basic logic flow.

However it seems one `n`command at the initial `if` skips the whole `if` ... `elsif` ... `else` statement.

Consider this example captured after having seen the effect (it won't run, but you get the idea):

```perl-db
  DB<5> l 3136-3164
3136    sub manage_key($$$)
3137    {
3138:       my ($ks, $ID, $params) = @_;
3139:       my $me = 'manage_key';
3140:       my $result = 1;
3141:       my ($key_type, $instance) = split_ID($ID);
3142
3143:       $ks->clear_errors();
3144:b      if (defined(my $PIN = $params->{(PK_PIN)})) {
3145:           if (my $container = $ks->get_container($key_type, $instance, $PIN)) {
3146                #...
3147            } else {
3148:               my $err = ks_error_message($ks, ': ');
3149
3150:               verbose(-1, "failed to get key $ID$err");
3151:               show_ks_errors($ks);
3152:               $result = 0;
3153            }
3154:       } elsif (my $container = $ks->_get_container($key_type, $instance)) {
3155            #...
3156        } else {
3157:           my $err = ks_error_message($ks, ': ');
3158
3159:           verbose(-1, "failed to get key $ID$err");
3160:           show_ks_errors($ks);
3161:           $result = 0;
3162        }
3163==>     return $result;
3164    }
```

The debugger session (where `$params->{(PK_PIN)}` was not set) was:

```perl-db
main::manage_key(./keytool.pl:3144):        if (defined(my $PIN = $params->{(PK_PIN)})) {
  DB<3> n
main::manage_key(./keytool.pl:3163):        return $result;
  DB<3> x $result
0  1
#...
  DB<6> x $params->{(PK_PIN)}
0  undef
```

So my expectation was that the `n` command would stop again at line 3154 where the `elsif` test should happen. But instead that part (that was actually executed) had been skipped until the end of the compound statement.

I wonder: Does the Perl debugger do that, or does the Perl compiler optimize the "empty" `if` away, even if the condition has a side effect?

I should mention: Perl 5.18.2 on x86-64 (SLES12 SP5)

## Player's Example

As some wanted a runnable example, here's a stupid equivalent (it does not do anything reasonable):

```perl-db
  DB<1> R
Warning: some settings and command-line options may be lost!

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(baz.pl:30):      manage_key(1,2,3);
  DB<1> manage_key(0,2,3)
main::manage_key(baz.pl:12):        if (defined(my $PIN = f($ks))) {
  DB<<2>> n
main::manage_key(baz.pl:13):            if (my $container = g($ID)) {
  DB<<2>> r
list context return from main::manage_key:
0  1

  DB<2> manage_key(undef,2,3)
main::manage_key(baz.pl:12):        if (defined(my $PIN = f($ks))) {
  DB<<3>> n
main::manage_key(baz.pl:27):        return $result;
  DB<<3>> l 1-30
1       #!/usr/bin/perl
2:      use strict;
3:      use warnings;
4
5:      sub f($) { my $x = shift; }
6:      sub g($) { my $y = shift; }
7       sub manage_key($$$)
8       {
9:          my ($ks, $ID, $params) = @_;
10:         my $result = 1;
11
12:b        if (defined(my $PIN = f($ks))) {
13:             if (my $container = g($ID)) {
14                  #...
15              } else {
16:                 my $err = 'blabla';
17
18:                 $result = 0;
19              }
20:         } elsif (my $container = g($params)) {
21              #...
22          } else {
23:             my $err = 'blabla';
24
25:             $result = 0;
26          }
27==>       return $result;
28      }
29
30:     manage_key(1,2,3);
```

You can see if the first condition is not met, then `n` skips the whole statement.

Comment: No, Perl doesn't do such things. Please, provide a runnable code that demonstrates the behaviour.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you could easily have verified that `my $container = g($params)` does get executed (doesn't get "optimized away").

Answer (score 1):

Use `s`, not `n`, to *step* into subroutine calls in the debugger.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

sub check {
    say "SUB";
    return time
}

my %H = (ZERO => 0);

if (defined(my $pin = $H{MISSING})) {
    say "IF";
} elsif (my $pop = $H{ZERO} * check()) {
    say "ELSIF";
} else {
    say "ELSE";
}
say "Done.";
```

You can see the sub still runs (because of the side effect), but it's not shown in the debugger. That's probably what happened in your case, too: one of the elsif's was entered, but there were no signs of it.

Using `n`:

```
perl -d 2.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.51
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(2.pl:11):    my %H = (ZERO => 0);
  DB<1> n
main::(2.pl:13):    if (defined(my $pin = $H{MISSING})) {
  DB<1> n
SUB
main::(2.pl:18):        say "ELSE";
  DB<1> n
ELSE
main::(2.pl:20):    say "Done.";
```

Using `s`:

```
main::(2.pl:11):    my %H = (ZERO => 0);
  DB<1> s
main::(2.pl:13):    if (defined(my $pin = $H{MISSING})) {
  DB<1> s
main::check(2.pl:7):        say "SUB";
main::check(2.pl:8):        return time
  DB<1> s
SUB
main::check(2.pl:9):    }
  DB<1> s
main::(2.pl:18):        say "ELSE";
  DB<1> s
ELSE
main::(2.pl:20):    say "Done.";
  DB<1> s
Done.
```

Comment: So `if` is considered to be one single statement, even if there are multiple branches? However if the branches are not empty, then `n` actually stops inside the corresponding branch!

Comment: If you remove the `say` commands from the if branches, you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> So my expectation was that the n command would stop again at line 3154

The debugger only breaks on statements. There's no statement at line 3154. `my $container = $ks->_get_container($key_type, $instance)` is part of the statement starting at line 3144.

`my $container = $ks->_get_container($key_type, $instance)` is executed (represented by `c` being printed below). It's not optimized away. You just can't break halfway into a statement.

```
$ perl -d -e'
   print( "a\n" );
   if ( print( "b\n" ), 0 ) { }
   elsif ( print( "c\n" ), 0 ) { }
   print( "d\n" );
'

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.77
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:2):      print( "a\n" );
  DB<1> n
a
main::(-e:3):      if ( print( "b\n" ), 0 ) { }
  DB<1> n
b
c
main::(-e:5):      print( "d\n" );
  DB<1> n
d
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
S<h q>, S<h R> or S<h o> to get additional info.
  DB<1>
```

Comment: Line 3154 is `} elsif (my $container = $ks->_get_container($key_type, $instance)) {`, something that *can* be executed.

Comment: Re "*something that can be executed*", Sorry, got the code from the other snippet. But that doesn't change anything. There's no statement at line 3154. I didn't say anything about "something that can be executed". If I write `4 + <line break> 5`, Perl isn't going to step onto the second line either. Because again, there's no statement on the second line.

Comment: But there's a difference for `if` ... `elseif` ...: Only if the `if` part failed the `elsif` part is attempted. Also, as can be seen from the listing, there are line numbers with a `:` at the end; those seem to be the lines with a "breakable" statement, and the `elsif` line is among those.

Comment: No, there's not. The same applies to `f() && g()` and `f() ? g() : h()`. Just like `if`-`elsif`, part of the statement can be skipped based on the evaluation of expressions earlier in the statement. And the debugger doesn't break in the middle of those either. I don't know how many times I can tell you, but **the debugger only breaks on statements**. PERIOD.